Sum of all possible numbers created from a set of digits.
I am currently interested in the following problem:

Given a set of digits from 0 to 9, with repeats allowed, what is the sum of all the numbers created by taking digits from that list (with frequency not more than it appears in the list). Note that you neither have to use all numbers in the list, nor having to use a number as many times as it appears in the list.
For example: with a set $S = \{0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6\}$, you can create the numbers $101, 40416, 41604$, $6$ and you can't create $11101$ (more $1$s than in the set), $124$ ($2$ not in the list).

My idea is that for the list we create a map that basically count how many of that digit is in the set (for example with that set $S$ we have $0$ and $6$ appear once, $1$ and $4$ appeared twice, all other ones does not appear). Then I decided to create a sequence $(k_i)_{i=0}^9$ for this purpose, as well as a number $n = |S| \stackrel{\text{obtained by definition}}{=} \sum_{i=0}^9 k_i$.
Next up, I tried to not evaluate everything all at once, but instead based on individual digits, and $0$. For example, if the set $S$ only has $1$s and $0$s, what would the sum be? If this is solvable, we can apply it to other digits and add them to the sum (e.g. if we know how to calculate based on $k_1 \ 1$s and $n$ zeros, call the result $f(k_1, n)$, then we can use this to calculate the sum for any other digit $k_i$ by $f(k_i, n) = i * f(k_i, n)$.
Which is why I am interested in calculating the function $f(k_1, n)$ itself. First, I define $g(k, n)$ as the sum of all the possible numbers created by replacing $k$ 0s in a string of $0$s of length $n$ with $1$. From there: $$f(k_1, n) = \sum_{k=0}^{k_1} g(k, n)$$ so now the problem reduces to evaluating $g(k, n)$ for inputs $k$ and $n$, which I found a way for. For every "location" on the string (basically the unit digit, hundreds, thousand digit, idk) there is $\begin{pmatrix}n - 1 \\ k - 1\end{pmatrix}$ way of placing other $1$s, which would mean that if the digit is at the location $i$ away from the end of the string, the sum would be added by $10^i * \begin{pmatrix}n - 1 \\ k - 1\end{pmatrix}$. We can make calculation faster by realizing that we are effectively evaluating a geometric sum with first term $\begin{pmatrix}n - 1 \\ k - 1\end{pmatrix}$ and common ratio $10$ with $n$ terms so $$g(n, k) = \frac{10 ^ n - 1}{9} * \begin{pmatrix}n - 1 \\ k - 1\end{pmatrix}$$.
With that said, my questions are:

Is there a faster way to evaluate $f(k_1, n)$ based on $g(k, n)$?
How do I continue from here? I have a very vague idea, but it's nice to have some direction. I was thinking that if we calculate $f(k_i, n)$ for all digits $0...9$ and then multiply them all, it would be the result, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Thanks for reading!

A simpler problem to solve is to find the total of the numbers you can make using all available digits (allowing for repetitions). Once you have this, an idea might be to apply this for all distinct subsets of $S$.

@ChrisLewis Thanks! I'll note it down. The problem is how to actually evaluate the sums of all those permutations. Also I doubt iterating over all subsets of $S$ is practical, there OUGHT to be some better way.
